# How to stop another bitcoind service?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I created two `bitcoind` service in my server.
First using default configuration, and second use new configuration.
I am able to stop first `bitcoind` using `bitcoin-cli stop`, but the second `bitcoind` still running. How to safely stop the second `bitcoind` without forcing to kill it ?

Comment: Not an answer, but a SIGTERM or SiGINT will cause a graceful shutdown of bitcoind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bitcoin-cli` has a `-datadir` option so you can specify the data directory of your other bitcoind instance. It will use that parameter to read the bitcoin.conf and `.cookie` files in the other data directory so that it can connect to the other bitcoind instance. With that parameter, you can send RPC commands to it, including the `stop` command.

Alternatively, you can stop bitcoind by finding its PID (using `ps`) and the `kill` command. `kill` be default uses `SIGTERM` so bitcoind will actually safely shutdown by going through its shutdown process.

Answer (score 1):

`bitcoin-cli` accepts a `-conf` parameter. Use that to point to the config of the second bitcoind client (which would contain the rpc details), and then shut it down as normal.

You can also use `-rpcpassword`, `-rpcport`, and `-rpcuser` to supply the details manually.